# Columns+Rows vs Stack for static sized grid?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of widgets (from a list of objects that have an x and y coordinate value) of the same size I want display in a grid arrangement, the size and placement wont change.

My initial thought is to use 2 for loops for the columns and rows and pass the widgets as children accordingly.

But would a Stack widget or CustomMultiChildLayout be more performant and suited for this? Given that columns and rows are made to be more dynamically sized and I don't need that functionality.

Edit: Image, literally just a grid of tiles at the moment. It's currently using loops of columns+rows. Yes I will be flipping the Y around to start at the bottom corner. [image]

Comment: Can you show an image of what you are trying to create please?

Comment: @KaushikChandru done. It's literally just a grid of tiles. Not much to see.

Comment: `CustomMultiChildLayout` is definitely a good idea (especially if you want to animate your children -  see `relayout` in the delegate's constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gridview to create this layout

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 15,
        children: List.generate(225, (index) {
          return GridTile(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.blue.shade200,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('$index'),
              )
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or In a wrap

```dart
Wrap(
 children: List.generate(225, (index) => Container( width: 20, height: 20, child: Text("$index")))
)
```

Comment: That seems like it would be the worst performance? Do you know how this compares in performance to the other methods I mentioned?

Comment: Gridview will have better performance than having nested rows and columns. Also you can create a list and add it in a wrap widget. Which will have no scroll or any extra contains.

Comment: But how does it compare to a Stack or CustomMultiChildLayout performance wise? That's my question.

Comment: A list view or gridview when used with a builder will only render the visible part of the widget and using a column and row will build everything even if it's not seen in the screen. So it's better to use list view builder or gridview builder

Comment: https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-problem-listview-vs-column-singlechildscrollview-43fdde0fa355 please check this

Comment: Everything is likely to be on the display at once, and if not then I will have it inside an InteractiveViewer.builder and hide widgets that are not on the display. This is a tile based game. I just need to know whether placing the widgets in a Stack with a specific x and y coordinate or using Columns/Rows/GridView is most performant to build.

Comment: Well i am also a unity developer so yes if you are planning to add some animations of tiles that would overlap other tiles or even a transition animation of all tiles setting in its place then definitely stack is a better option. Though performance wise gridview is better. Game is all about presentation and subtle animations. So the widget you choose is based on the requirement. If everything is visible at once then it won't make a big difference. Take a look at indexedstack also. That gives you an option to move a widget on top to probably animate it on some user input